# Error downloading artifacts from Maven

Tags: maven, grails

I sincerely apologize that I'm not able to copy a stacktrace, but my work is on a private network. On that network is also my Maven repository. We're trying to upgrade to Grails 2.4.3, but the Maven build fails when downloading several of the required jars.

All other jars are downloaded from my private mirror as specified, but for these particular jars, Maven tries to go out to the central repo, which I cannot access. I checked my private repo and those jars with their poms are there. My BuildGroovy.config has the right localRepo specified also.

What's making Maven suddenly connect to repo.maven.apache.org?? I should add that we don't have this problem when upgrading to Grails 2.4.2. That causes another problem (looking for groovy-all-2.4.2?) forcing us to use 2.4.3.

Thanks for ANY help.

Comment: What server? Artifactory? If you could share some non-proprietary configuration info it would help a lot. Sounds to me like you've got things wired up incorrectly, but without any details we can't do much more than offer up banal trivialities; "I feel your pain, man". "Been there, brah - hang tough, you'll get through this." "YOLO!". Well, maybe not yolo. You know what we meant.

Comment: Well, I don't know how much it helps, but we have a Nexus repo. We have several other non-Grails projects that build flawlessly, so that makes me think the wiring is right. Anything else I could add??

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes and try to read what you've provided as if that was all you knew about this problem. You've basically said "I believe everything is correctly configured; no, you can't see the configuration info; this usually works, very similar stuff works, this doesn't work though, please help me fix it." Did you try turning it off and back on again? That's about all I can come up with.

Comment: Well, would it help if I add that it's only the jars in the maven-grails-plugin that are attempting to connect to repo.maven.apache.org? All of my other dependencies are downloaded from the private repo, including the maven-grails-plugin.jar itself.